# Kubernetes ingress does not create rules in Alb/EKS when it has wildcard

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress, amazon-eks, aws-application-load-balancer

My post is to bring some details about a problem I was facing and the details of how I arrived at a solution, in case anyone else is experiencing something similar.

## FACT

- Kubernetes ingress does not create rules in Alb/EKS when it has wildcard.
- When trying to create overlapping paths in Kubernetes Ingress, requests are not routing as expected.
- Ingress cannot create paths with Wildcard.

## CAUSE

- The wildcard rule is not created in the ALB on AWS.
- When trying to wildcard the Ingress path in Kubernetes, errors occur in ingress / aws-load-balancer-controller.
- Ingress Logs:

`

```
Events:
  Type     Reason            Age                  From     Message
  ----     ------            ----                 ----     -------
  Warning  FailedBuildModel  53s (x974 over 11d)  ingress  Failed build model due to ingress: api-checkout/api-checkout-develop: prefix path shouldn't contain wildcards: /teste/*
```

`

- aws-load-balancer-controller logs:

kubectl logs -n kube-system deployment.apps/aws-load-balancer-controller

{"level":"error","ts":1669761828.7741847,"logger":"controller-runtime.manager.controller.ingress","msg":"Reconciler error","name":"api-checkout-max -shopify-develop","namespace":"api-checkout-max-shopify-develop","error":"ingress: api-checkout-max-shopify-develop/api-checkout-max-shopify-develop: prefix path shouldn't contain wildcards: /shopify/*"}

- It is only possible to create rules in the ALB containing wildcard, through the AWS Console.

## ACTION

- Instead of using "pathType: Prefix", use "pathType: ImplementationSpecific" when creating paths via yaml manifest in Kubernetes.
- This way the ingress can create the proper rules (even with Wildcard) in the Load Balancer / ALB in AWS.
- Source:
  https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/ingress/#path-types

> ImplementationSpecific: With this path type, matching is up to the IngressClass. Implementations can treat this as a separate pathType or treat it identically to Prefix or Exact path types.

- EXAMPLE:

```
---
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: $K8S_INGRESS_NAME_NGINX
  namespace: $K8S_NAMESPACE
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: alb
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/certificate-arn: $INGRESS_CERT_ARN,$INGRESS_CERT_SUBDOMAIN_ARN
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/ssl-policy: ELBSecurityPolicy-TLS-1-2-Ext-2018-06
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/listen-ports: '[{"HTTP": 80}, {"HTTPS": 443}]'
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/ssl-redirect: "443"
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/scheme: internet-facing
spec:
  rules:
    - host: $URL
      http:
        paths:
          - pathType: ImplementationSpecific
            path: "/teste"
            backend:
              service:
                name: $K8S_DEPLOY_NAME_NGINX_FRONTEND
                port:
                  number: $K8S_SERVICE_PORT_NGINX_FRONTEND
          - pathType: ImplementationSpecific
            path: "/teste/*"
            backend:
              service:
                name: $K8S_DEPLOY_NAME_NGINX_BACKEND
                port:
                  number: $K8S_SERVICE_PORT_NGINX_BACKEND
          - pathType: Prefix
            path: "/checkout"
            backend:
              service:
                name: $K8S_DEPLOY_NAME_NGINX_FRONTEND
                port:
                  number: $K8S_SERVICE_PORT_NGINX_FRONTEND
            path: "/"
            backend:
              service:
                name: $K8S_DEPLOY_NAME_NGINX_BACKEND
                port:
                  number: $K8S_SERVICE_PORT_NGINX_BACKEND
```

- When trying to create overlapping paths in Kubernetes Ingress, requests are not routing as expected.
- Ingress cannot create paths with Wildcard.